# path apps in django

Tags: django, path

I wanna get absolute path all installed_apps in "setting.py" .

```
app_list = [ app for app in Myproject.settings.INSTALLED_APPS ]
```

I list of application but how i can get absolute path all of them.

Thank you.

Comment: Do you mean url absolute path?  Or the path of the view?  Also, what are you planning on doing with the information once you have it?

Comment: I mean Url absolute path. I want get all name of classes define in app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Today I solved my problem. I write this code and its just working. For limited name class I find name of class that inherent from "models.Model" . you can change it and enjoy that.also this code find files in depth 1 of modules. it can change.

```
app_list = [app for app in training.settings.INSTALLED_APPS if "task" in app]
for module in app_list:
    module1 = __import__(module)
    temp = module1.__path__
    files_path = [temp[0] + os.sep + files_name for files_name in os.listdir(temp[0]) if
                  os.path.splitext(files_name)[1] == ".py"]

    p = re.compile(r'class\s*\w*\s*\(models.Model\):')
    for file in files_path:
        infile = open(file)
        text = infile.read()
        all_class = p.findall(text)
        print [class_name[6:][:-15] for class_name in all_class]
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not really possible to do what you want. I mean you can get *almost* there, but there's no real functionality for this, and in particular, Python doesn't distinguish between classes, methods, and variables. They all count as attributes of the module.

First, `INSTALLED_APPS` is a tuple of strings. So, in order to get any useful information, you're going to have load them as modules:

```
for app in settings.INSTALLED_APPS:
    module = __import__(app)
```

Then, once you have the actual module, you can call `dir` on it to get a list of its attributes:

```
for app in settings.INSTALLED_APPS:
    module = __import__(app)
    print dir(module)
```

And, that's about as far as you can go. It's going to output everything set in the module, not just classes. From here, about the only recourse I can think of to weed out everything but classes is to assume that naming conventions were followed and look for items that start with a capital letter. That's not exactly scientific, but that's all you got.